# Why it throws an error? `forms.py Cannot import model from models.py`

Tags: django, forms, django-models, django-forms

I am trying to use django forms. but whenever I try to import a Design model from **models.py** , I keep getting

> cannot import name Design

Here is my **forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from .models import Design 
class NewDesign(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = Design
            fields = ['category', 'designImage']
```

Here is my **models.py**

```
from django.db import models
class Design(models.Model):
    user=models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name='design_category', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    designImage=models.ImageField()
    timeuploaded=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user)
```

**I KEEP GETTING IMPORT ERROR**

> ImportError:cannot import name 'Design'
>   Both models.py and forms.py are inthe same App folder. I don't know why it is not working but it should work....Any help will be appreciated . Thanks

[error massege image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Eohj.png)

[project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZwyr.png)

both models.py andd forms.py are in the same directory..have worked with forms before but dont understand why not working now...Thanks

Comment: post full error trackback

Comment: You might have a circular import (`models.py` imports something from another module which imports from `models.py`). We can't tell because you haven't posted the full traceback and have only shown part of your `models.py` and `forms.py`.

Comment: Could you please share your directory structure?

Comment: @ Alasdai, Devang Padhiyar...Thanks for your kind reply . the error traceback image and my directory structure will be included in the original question edit

Comment: The error shows that forms has `from .models import Design` but models has `from . import forms`, so you have a circular import. You shouldn't normally have to import forms inside your `models.py`. How are you using it there.

Comment: kindly go through the question. I just included error traceback and project structure.Thanks

Comment: Thanks so so much to you guys... Just solved it. I removed  "from . import forms " in my models.py I am not using it. Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

You have a circular import, because `forms.py` has

```
from .models import Design
```

and `models.py` has

```
from . import forms
```

You shouldn't normally have to import `forms` inside your `models.py`, so if you aren't using it, just remove the import.

Comment: Thanks for your help, friends.... It worked as suggested by @Alasdair
Please I have a question about django-registration-redux(I am it for user authentication and verification)...
How could i prevent authenticated user from visiting the loggin page or register page... I know I would have to make little touch this 3rd party app to do this .. especially at the views.py
HERE IS THE LINK...
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55520516/djangohow-can-i-prevent-authenticated-user-from-both-register-and-login-page-in

Comment: That's a completely different problem, I'm afraid I can't help with that.