# Django:How can I prevent authenticated user from both register and login page in Django-registration-redux

Tags: django, view, django-views, registration, django-registration

I am currently using **Django-registration-redux** for my authentication system.
Already logged in user can visit the login and registration page again; which is not good enough. How can I prevent them from this since the views.py comes by default in **Django-registration-redux**
I think that should be done in the views.py that come with **Django-registration-redux**

**Here is the views.py**

```
"""
Views which allow users to create and activate accounts.

"""

from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView
from django.views.generic.edit import FormView
from django.conf import settings
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
from django.views.decorators.debug import sensitive_post_parameters
try:
    from django.utils.module_loading import import_string
except ImportError:
    from registration.utils import import_string


from registration import signals
# from registration.forms import RegistrationForm

REGISTRATION_FORM_PATH = getattr(settings, 'REGISTRATION_FORM', 'registration.forms.RegistrationFormUniqueEmail')
REGISTRATION_FORM = import_string( REGISTRATION_FORM_PATH )


class _RequestPassingFormView(FormView):
    """
    A version of FormView which passes extra arguments to certain
    methods, notably passing the HTTP request nearly everywhere, to
    enable finer-grained processing.

    """
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # Pass request to get_form_class and get_form for per-request
        # form control.
        form_class = self.get_form_class(request)
        form = self.get_form(form_class)
        return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=form))

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # Pass request to get_form_class and get_form for per-request
        # form control.
        form_class = self.get_form_class(request)
        form = self.get_form(form_class)
        if form.is_valid():
            # Pass request to form_valid.
            return self.form_valid(request, form)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form)

    def get_form_class(self, request=None):
        return super(_RequestPassingFormView, self).get_form_class()

    def get_form_kwargs(self, request=None, form_class=None):
        return super(_RequestPassingFormView, self).get_form_kwargs()

    def get_initial(self, request=None):
        return super(_RequestPassingFormView, self).get_initial()

    def get_success_url(self, request=None, user=None):
        # We need to be able to use the request and the new user when
        # constructing success_url.
        return super(_RequestPassingFormView, self).get_success_url()

    def form_valid(self, form, request=None):
        return super(_RequestPassingFormView, self).form_valid(form)

    def form_invalid(self, form, request=None):
        return super(_RequestPassingFormView, self).form_invalid(form)


class RegistrationView(_RequestPassingFormView):
    """
    Base class for user registration views.

    """
    disallowed_url = 'registration_disallowed'
    form_class = REGISTRATION_FORM
    http_method_names = ['get', 'post', 'head', 'options', 'trace']
    success_url = None
    template_name = 'registration/registration_form.html'

    @method_decorator(sensitive_post_parameters('password1', 'password2'))
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Check that user signup is allowed before even bothering to
        dispatch or do other processing.

        """
        if not self.registration_allowed(request):
            return redirect(self.disallowed_url)
        return super(RegistrationView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def form_valid(self, request, form):
        new_user = self.register(request, form)
        success_url = self.get_success_url(request, new_user)

        # success_url may be a simple string, or a tuple providing the
        # full argument set for redirect(). Attempting to unpack it
        # tells us which one it is.
        try:
            to, args, kwargs = success_url
            return redirect(to, *args, **kwargs)
        except ValueError:
            return redirect(success_url)

    def registration_allowed(self, request):
        """
        Override this to enable/disable user registration, either
        globally or on a per-request basis.

        """
        return True

    def register(self, request, form):
        """
        Implement user-registration logic here. Access to both the
        request and the full cleaned_data of the registration form is
        available here.

        """
        raise NotImplementedError


class ActivationView(TemplateView):
    """
    Base class for user activation views.

    """
    http_method_names = ['get']
    template_name = 'registration/activate.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        activated_user = self.activate(request, *args, **kwargs)
        if activated_user:
            success_url = self.get_success_url(request, activated_user)
            try:
                to, args, kwargs = success_url
                return redirect(to, *args, **kwargs)
            except ValueError:
                return redirect(success_url)
        return super(ActivationView, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def activate(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Implement account-activation logic here.

        """
        raise NotImplementedError

    def get_success_url(self, request, user):
        raise NotImplementedError
```

Here is my main/project urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url( 'admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$', views.home, name='homepage'),
    url(r'^user/', include('User.urls')),
    #url(r'^accounts/register/$', MyRegistrationView.as_view(), 
]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Thanks, any help will be appreciated

**Below are the file showing identation error**
[indentaion error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IjX6Q.png)
[views file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gUOyp.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the dispatch method of your views you can check if the user is authenticated and redirect them to another page, for example:

```
class RegistrationView(_RequestPassingFormView):
    ...
    @method_decorator(sensitive_post_parameters('password1', 'password2'))
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Check that user signup is allowed before even bothering to
        dispatch or do other processing.

        """
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            return redirect('some_url')
        if not self.registration_allowed(request):
            return redirect(self.disallowed_url)
        return super(RegistrationView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

The `if user.is_authenticated` prevents both **logged-in and not-logged-in** user from accessing the registration page.

```
class RegistrationView(_RequestPassingFormView):
    """
    Base class for user registration views.
    """
    disallowed_url = 'registration_disallowed'
    form_class = REGISTRATION_FORM
    http_method_names = ['get', 'post', 'head', 'options', 'trace']
    success_url = None
    template_name = 'registration/registration_form.html'

    @method_decorator(sensitive_post_parameters('password1', 'password2'))
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Check that user signup is allowed before even bothering to
        dispatch or do other processing.

        """
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated:
            return redirect('/')
        if not self.registration_allowed(request):
            return redirect(self.disallowed_url)
        return super(RegistrationView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def form_valid(self, request, form):
        new_user = self.register(request, form)
        success_url = self.get_success_url(request, new_user)

        # success_url may be a simple string, or a tuple providing the
        # full argument set for redirect(). Attempting to unpack it
        # tells us which one it is.
        try:
            to, args, kwargs = success_url
            return redirect(to, *args, **kwargs)
        except ValueError:
            return redirect(success_url)

    def registration_allowed(self, request):
        """
        Override this to enable/disable user registration, either
        globally or on a per-request basis.

        """
        return True

    def register(self, request, form):
        """
        Implement user-registration logic here. Access to both the
        request and the full cleaned_data of the registration form is
        available here.

        """
        raise NotImplementedError
```

Comment: I did as you suggested. Immediately I add the two lines of code , i am getting INDENTATION ERROR. while I think everything is properly indented...
I just added two images showing the errors.

Comment: Hi friends, I just notice now while testing the code the if request.user.is_authenticated: return redirect('some_url') not only prevent authenticated user from accessing register page but also redirect not-loggeed-in user... Please what Can I do ???? don't seem to understand.. I will update the original post with the view here. Thanks

Comment: @ray that's weird, can you post the code of the view updated?

Comment: I just updated the question with all codes in the views.py .... also i try implementing the same thing for the login view, i am getting the same result. 
@pedro
That is, both authenticated and not-authenticate user are also prevented from the login page also. Thanks to you guys...Any help will be appreciated.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55541801/django-registration-preventing-logged-inauthenticated-from-accessing-registra

Comment: everything works fine when i upgraded my django version to 2.1 and registrtion-redux to 2.5