# Django-registration: Preventing logged-in(authenticated) from accessing registration page results to registration page denied for all user

Tags: view, django-views, django-authentication, django-registration

**Hi everyone,
I am currently using Django-registration-redux for a django project**

In my attempt to prevent autenticated user from accessing Register page and Login page, I needed to make few changes to the **views.py** serving those 2 pages. 
 I used

`if self.request.user.is_authenticated:
   return redirect('mainhomepage')`

at the both the register and login view as suggested in this link below which I posted recently [Preventing already authenticated user from accessing the register page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55520516/djangohow-can-i-prevent-au**thenticated-user-from-both-register-and-login-page-in)

The solution provided worked but it also prevent not-logged-in user from accessing the registration page

**Here is the views.py for register page**

```
class RegistrationView(_RequestPassingFormView):
"""
Base class for user registration views.

"""
disallowed_url = 'registration_disallowed'
form_class = REGISTRATION_FORM
http_method_names = ['get', 'post', 'head', 'options', 'trace']
success_url = None
template_name = 'registration/registration_form.html'

@method_decorator(sensitive_post_parameters('password1', 'password2'))
def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    """
    Check that user signup is allowed before even bothering to
    dispatch or do other processing.

    """
    if self.request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('mainhomepage')
    if not self.registration_allowed(request):
        return redirect(self.disallowed_url)
    return super(RegistrationView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

def form_valid(self, request, form):
    new_user = self.register(request, form)
    success_url = self.get_success_url(request, new_user)

    # success_url may be a simple string, or a tuple providing the
    # full argument set for redirect(). Attempting to unpack it
    # tells us which one it is.
    try:
        to, args, kwargs = success_url
        return redirect(to, *args, **kwargs)
    except ValueError:
        return redirect(success_url)

def registration_allowed(self, request):
    """
    Override this to enable/disable user registration, either
    globally or on a per-request basis.

    """
    return True

def register(self, request, form):
    """
    Implement user-registration logic here. Access to both the
    request and the full cleaned_data of the registration form is
    available here.

    """
    raise NotImplementedError
```

As you can see: I added the

```
if self.request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('mainhomepage')
```

so that only authenticated users can be redirected to the **mainhomepage** url

**However both authenticated and not autheticated are automatically directed to that page**

Please what else can I do to solve this. both authenticated and non-authenticated are redirected to that page. Meanwhile the **if statement** only said that authenticated user should be redirected.

**IN SHORT, I can no longer access the register page again when I AM LOGGED OUT because irrespective om the log in status, user is redirected to homepage. Thereby making it impossible to make new registration on the page... ANY HELP PLEASE??**